# Applying TDD/unit testing for config transforms?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, tdd, tfsbuild

Does anyone know of any techniques or frameworks that can be applied to effectively unit test config transforms, particularly on a build server?

For example, if I add a new connection string to the base config, is there any way to write an automated test to ensure that the correct value is applied to the QA and product configs?

Expanding on that idea, it would be nice to be able to specify certain items in the base config that should have transforms, to catch those inevitable situations where the transform hasn't been added to an environment's config.

Answer (score 7):

I've ended up using the process below:

[Create a link](http://documentation.flatredball.com/frb/docs/?title=Visual_Studio_Tutorials%3aAdd_As_Link) to your web.config and transform files from your test project in visual studio.
Change the files properties to "copy if newer".
Add a nuget reference to [Microsoft Xml Document Transformation](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Xdt/)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Xdt -Pre
```

You should now be able to load the web.config and its transforms into a unit test, something like the one below:
Note: I'm using [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) and [Fluent Assertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/) for this test.

```
[Test]
public void Transform_WhenUsingAlpha_ConnectionStringShouldPointToAlpha()
{
    using (var webConfig = LoadWebConfig())
    {
        var transformWasSuccessful = DoXmlTransform(webConfig, "Web.Alpha.config");
        var connectionString = 
            webConfig.SelectNodes(
            "//connectionStrings/add[@name='ApplicationServices']/@connectionString")[0].Value;

        transformWasSuccessful.Should().BeTrue();
        connectionString.Should().Contain("_Alpha");
    }
}

public XmlTransformableDocument LoadWebConfig()
{
    var document = new XmlTransformableDocument();
    document.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    document.Load("web.config");
    return document;
}

private bool DoXmlTransform(XmlTransformableDocument webConfig, string transformFile)
{
    using (var transform = new XmlTransformation(transformFile))
    {
        return transform.Apply(webConfig);
    }
}
```

I've tested this approach against our TeamCity build server and it works fine. On a side note it also works with NCrunch.

If you want to do manual checks on web.config transforms the [SlowCheetah - XML Transforms extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't integrate with your build server, but the [SlowCheetah XML Transforms extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) gives you a convenient way to generate the result of your transforms and make sure they're what you want.

[SlowCheetah is also available as a NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/).

Via [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx)

There's also the option of rolling your own solution using the microsoft.web.xdt nuget package. Here's [how to invoke XDT from code](http://sedodream.com/2013/02/02/HowToInvokeXDTFromCode.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not aware of any way with SlowCheetah to verify that a particular value is present in the transformed config. For example, if the transform is removed from web.debug.config, the value from the web.config will just be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what I was looking for, but I did stumble upon [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester), which seems to provide a fairly reasonable mechanism for validating values in config files. See [this](http://scottmuc.com/blog/development/pester-bdd-for-the-system-administrator/) blog post for details.